# Cannot commit after reverting one file from previous commit

Tags: git, android-studio

What I did:

1. I had a file that was wrongly deleted in a previous commit. In "Version control" -> "Log" I clicked "Revert selected changes" on the file in changelist on the right.[image]
2. Android Studio showed "Patch successfully applied"

After that nothing happened — it didn't appear in any changelist. How do I commit my revert?

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio's "Revert" is not equivalent to `git revert`. It behaves like `svn revert` discarding the changes before `svn commit`, or `git checkout -- filepath` discarding the changes before `git add`.

It seems Android Studio does not have a `git revert` button. So do it in the command line instead. If the previous commit touches a few files, assuming the commit is A, `git checkout A^ -- filepath` to "revert" the one file only and then add and commit.

Comment: Thank you! I was actually trying to revert one file from a commit history. Is your answer relevant?